# What is the difference between android: and no android:

Tags: android, android-layout

These below are some style code in a style.xml . 
What I want to ask is why it has two same lines describing the actionBarStyle.
The only difference is one have android: and the other don't.

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: First one is used for **ActionBarSherlock** library, to support devices which does not have native ActinoBar. Second is standard way for **API >= 11**

Comment: Thanks, I have included ActionBarSherlock library, but if I only write the first line, it won't work. If i only write the second line it works. Is it better to write both lines all the time?

Comment: First line works for devices API < 11, Second for API >= 11, so yes, Use both lines, for consistent result.

Comment: if you have the ActionBarSherlock used in your application and devices with API<11 should be able to display the ActionBar you will need to use both items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first one is used by libraries .

second one is the official of android, which requires an API level.

you should always use both if you want to support all API levels (that are supported by the library).